# If/else in javascript doesnt return else for undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I just started learning JS 3 weeks ago so I might overlook something simple. 
I am trying to make a Facebook chemistry bot (in Dutch) using the npm modules periodic-table and facebook-chat-api. 
Every function based on periodic-table is working fine except for getting the molar weight. If I typ in something that is not a molecule, it doesn't go to the else statement while for all my other cases this does happen. This is the case:

```
case 'mw':

    var regex = /((Uu[a-z]|[A-Z][a-z]?)\d*)/g;
    var mol = (commandText.match(regex) || []).join(' ');

    if(util.atomicMass != undefined && util.atomicMass(mol) != undefined) {
        api.sendMessage("De molaire massa van " + commandText + " is: " + util.atomicMass(mol) + " g/mol", event.threadID)

    }
    else {
        api.sendMessage("Fout, onjuiste opmaak", event.threadID)

    }

    break;
```

I have also tried

```
if (util == undefined || (util.atomicMass != undefined && util.atomicMass(mol) != undefined)) {
```

instead, but with no luck.

The error I get is:

```
ERR! ERROR in listen -->  TypeError: Cannot read property 'atomicMass' of undefined
ERR! ERROR in listen -->      at C:\Users\Bd\node_modules\periodic-table\util.js:16:54
```

While I do have `util` defined at the beginning and it works just fine with existing molecules. With nonsense input, it doesn't give me the wanted error.
`console.log(util)` gives me `{ atomicMass: [Function: atomicMass] }` so it is defined.

My whole code is:
http://pastebin.com/6u2bMbXF

Or could there be something wrong with util itself why this doesn't work?

Edit:

```
   if (typeof util.atomicMass(mol) == "object")
```

Also does not work.

Comment: I think this is a bit fishy as well: `commandText.match(regex) || []`  since match returns null when there are no matches, but could potentially return other falsy values (?)

Comment: The regex shouldn't be the problem because if I input something that does match the regex but is not an element I still get the same error. Also, when I input something that does not match the regex I get that same error.

Comment: _“and facebook-chat-api”_ – there is no such thing any more …

Comment: CBroe, yes there is and it works like a charm: https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [try ... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement.

Example for your code:

```
try {
  api.sendMessage("De molaire massa van " + commandText + " is: " + util.atomicMass(mol) + " g/mol", event.threadID);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    api.sendMessage("Fout, onjuiste opmaak", event.threadID);
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

*Checking and throwing isn't necessary, you could just log all exceptions and always send same text to user.*

PS: I'm not sure if it is common in JS, it is more Pythonic way (EAFP)

Answer (score 1):

The error you get refers to the periodic-table node_module.

line 16:
something with  pt.symbols[vector[1]] is not defined.
you can debug the nodejs code or add console.log to find out what is the issue.

...

```
}, [])
.reduce(function(sum, vector) {
  return sum + (vector[0] * pt.symbols[vector[1]].atomicMass.split('(')[0]);
}, 0);
```

}

...

Comment: Yes, the atomicMass in line 16 will be undefined if you try it with a wrong input that doesn't have an atomic mass. So this returns undefined as can also be seen in my error message, so that's not strange. The mystery to me is why it doesn't proceed to go to my else statement when it is undefined.

Comment: It's not a strange. You are trying to resolve something that is not exists. The if statement should refer to the object before addressing its property .. In case you are trying to resolve obj.foo and foo is not defined. Nothing major will occur but if the obj is not valid. Its an error alright

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for me how I can workaround this? I've tried for days now with no success.

Comment: @bdbdbd Just use try/catch.

Comment: As @stek29 mentioned use try catch block. On the catch block you can add your code in case it fails and in the finally block you can add other logic.  try{}catch(e){}finally{}